# Running count in Python is not held

Tags: python

I have two running counts in this code, and when I hit 'stop' to get a summary, the entries that should populate my running count are returning 0. It was working and then it wasn't, and I have no idea why.

```
print ('Property Type   Taxes')

n = str() #Property Type
m = float() #Amount of taxes

totalC = float(0.0) #total taxes of Commercial property
totalR = float(0.0) #total taxes of Residential property


while True:
    n = input()
    if n == 'stop':
        print ('Sum of Taxes' '   ' 'Average of Taxes')
        print ('Residential Properties' '   ', totalR)
        print ('Commercial Properties' '   ', totalC)
    m = float(input())
    print (n, '      ', m)
    if n == ('Commercial' or 'commercial'):
        totalC += m
    elif n == ('Residential' or 'residential'):
        totalR += m
```

There's only so much teaching my professor has actually done and the textbook we're using is extremely limited. I could not understand the variety of 'while' conditions, so I had `while n != 'stop'` as the condition and then I changed it to `while True` after seeing another thread. It worked after this and then stopped working after a few tries without having changed anything else.

Comment: You should format your code properly.  Particularly in Python, indentation is **everything** and so proper formatting is crucial.

Comment: I'd suggest printing something if `n` isn't recognised, it helps to ensure that your code is doing what you expect

Answer (score 0):

`n == ('Commercial' or 'commercial')` is checking if `n` is equal to the result of the boolean expression `('Commercial' or 'commercial')`.  Boolean expressions evaluate to the last operand evaluated. Since `or` is used and `'Commercial'` is true, this expression returns `'Commercial'`.

If `n` is `'Commercial'` this will do what you expect, but otherwise it will not.

You likely wanted:

```
n == 'Commercial' or n == 'commercial'
```

But even better would be to first lower case `n` and then compare it to `commercial`.

```
n.lower() == 'commercial'
```

You might also use `in` to check an input against a set of possibilities.

```
n in {'Commercial', 'commercial'}
```